# Crash when unarchived data to CNContact

Tags: swift, cncontact, nskeyedunarchiver

Hello I have a crash when unarchived data to CNContact :

**in line :** `var decodedContacts = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [CNContact.self], from: archived) as? [CNContact?]`

**the error log :**

NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [CNContact.self], from: contactsData) as? [CNContact?] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'root' was of unexpected class 'NSArray' (0x1d97a9ed8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]. Allowed classes are: {( "'CNContact' (0x1d9881018) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Contacts.framework]" )}" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'root' was of unexpected class Allowed classes are: {( "'CNContact' (0x1d9881018) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Contacts.framework]" )}}

```
import Contacts

class ContactsManager {

static let numberOfSavedContacts = 12

static let shared = ContactsManager()
private init() {
    loadContacts()
}

private(set) var contacts: [CNContact?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: numberOfSavedContacts)

func add(contact: CNContact, at index: Int, phone: CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>? = nil) {
    if index < ContactsManager.numberOfSavedContacts {
        let editContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
        if phone != nil {
            editContact.phoneNumbers = [phone!]
        }
        contacts[index] = editContact
        saveContacts()
    }
}

func deleteContact(_ index: Int) {
    if index < ContactsManager.numberOfSavedContacts {
        contacts[index] = nil
        saveContacts()
    }
}

func saveContacts() {
    do {
        let contactsData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:contacts,requiringSecureCoding:false)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(contactsData, forKey: "contacts")
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}


func loadContacts() {
    if let contactsData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "contacts") as? Data {
        do {
            if var decodedContacts = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, CNContact.self, NSNull.self], from: contactsData) as? [CNContact?] {
                print(decodedContacts)
                contacts = decodedContacts
            } else {
                print("decodedContacts is nil")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is unclear: `contactsData` is `Data`, So `archived` is "data of data", then you expect `decodedContacts` which unarchived from `archived` to be Contact.

Comment: It's an example I saw in another question. Now I've edited the code here, and when I run it, I get the following in the console:

Comment: @RoeiNadam Please do not post details in comments. Please put those details in your question.

Comment: @HangarRash ok, edit.

Comment: `ofClasses: [NSArray.self, CNContact.self]` or `ofClasses: [[CNContact].self]`, as I don't know if the bridge is well managed there between Swift Array and NSArray.

Comment: @Larme for [NSArray.self, CNContact.self] I run an get in console "value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSNull'" , and for  [CNContact].self] I get error before run "Cannot convert value of type '[CNContact].Type' to expected element type 'Array<AnyClass>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'any AnyObject.Type')"

Comment: `[NSArray.self, CNContact.self, NSNull.self]` then, I didn't see that you might have saved `nil` value (in the init)

Comment: @Larme Thank its works (-:

Answer (score 0):

`NSKeyedUnarchiver` is the "old way" of archiving objects. It's Objective-C oriented.

Seeing the error:
`was of unexpected class 'NSArray'`

Then, you need to specify you'll encounter `NSArray` objects when decoding:

```
ofClasses: [NSArray.self, CNContact.self]
```

Now, you get another error: `was of unexpected class 'NSNull'"`. `NSNull` ~ `nil`.

You are saving `nil` contacts with `Array(repeating: nil, count: numberOfSavedContacts)`.

So you need to tell the unarchiver that you might encounter nil values:

```
ofClasses: [NSArray.self, NSNull.self, CNContact.self]
```

I don't know why you save `nil` value, that's strange though, you might want to change that behavior.